# How to catch an ENTER event and convert it into a TAB event?

Tags: javascript, jquery, primefaces

i'm looking for a *JQUERY or JS script* to catch onkeydown *Primefaces InputText* property with  ---> event.keyCode == 13 and **convert it** into a event.keyCode = 9.

I tried to script a solution like this in the example below.

But it doesn't works for me.
**I tried different way to catch the event, cancel it and re-launch another event, but the problem persist.**
So, can I convert it or launch another event to prevent the ENTER event? I don't wanna delete the possibility to press Enter to the user, I just wanna convert it.

```
temp0.onkeydown = function(e) { 
    if (e.which == 13) { 
        e.preventDefault();
        var event = new Event('keydown', {bubbles: true, cancelable: true});
        event.which = 9;
        this.dispatchEvent(event);
    } 
}
```

Right now i'm using *Primefaces 6.0 and a TreeTable* for my InputText. I test the problem with TAB and it works perfectly, but with the Enter key the problem seems to block the entire table.

I read everything about this argument, but i was not able to find anything useful. I hope that somebody will able to help me. Thanks in advance.

Comment: what does 'blocking the entire table' mean? What happens? Errors? No response? Not a response you expect? Tried PF 6.1 or 6.2 (or 7.0-RC1) just for this issue?

Comment: Try using this, Hope it will work...$(this).trigger("keydown", [9]);

Comment: @Kukeltje it means that the table is not updating. I can't try with PF 6.1 or 6.2 becouse the entire project is based on this version and I can't change it in 10 mins, it costs weeks to be tested in the entire project. This is why I need a script to fix this problem :D If this fix exists, becouse i'm not sure :(

Comment: @CodeBlaze I'll try, thank you :D

Comment: I said "TRY for just this issue", just to see if in a newer version this single issue is fixed in a newer version. It should be easy to test since you most likely already have made an [mcve] since that is what you should have done like [ask] states. And if something is fixed in a newer version you have an pointer to where to look for a fix for your case. And 'blocking' the table is sort of something completely different than 'not updating' and still unclear what you actually mean. Please describe as a developer and debug what does happen.... Cheers